# Javascript not declaring variables

Tags: javascript, document.write

i'm new to JavaScript i have this script and i want to declare a variable on a if but on document.write , returns nothing what am i doing wrong ?

```
<head>
    <script>
        (function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                var NetworkStatus = document.getElementById("status"),
                    isOnline = navigator.onLine;

                if (isOnline) {
                    NetworkStatus.innerHTML = "Online";
                    NetworkStatus.className = "online";
                    var person="John Doe";
                } else {
                    NetworkStatus.innerHTML = "Offline";
                    NetworkStatus.className = "offline";
                    var person="Santa Claus";
                }
            }, 100);
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="status"></h1>
    <script>
        document.write(person + "<br>");
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd love to see the link for the tool which you use to indent.

Comment: Java and javascript are two different languages

Comment: `person` is not accessible from outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just all wrong, why use an IIFE and a timeout when all you have to do is add the script in the tag at the end of the DOM.

Also, you're setting the innerHTML of the element, and using document.write, which will overwrite the document ?

```
<head>
    <title>I messed up</title>
</head>
<body>
     <h1 id="status"></h1>

    <script>
        var NetworkStatus = document.getElementById("status"),
            isOnline = navigator.onLine;

            if (isOnline) {
                var person = "John Doe";
                NetworkStatus.innerHTML = "Online " + person;
                NetworkStatus.className = "online";
            } else {
                var person = "Santa Claus";
                NetworkStatus.innerHTML = "Offline " + person;
                NetworkStatus.className = "offline";

            }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). which creates its own scope

And that's where it stays

Do this :

`window.person="Santa Claus";`

Instead of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

`var` sets the scope of the variable to the function it is declared within. You are trying to `document.write` it from outside that function, so it is out of scope and inaccessible.

Use `window.person` instead of `var person`.

Answer (score 0):

The function executes after 100ms which means the person variable has no value when the page loads.